# Как работает xhci контроллер?

Tags: драйвер, intel

Исследую работу xhci контроллера intel, но не могу понять соответствие между документацией и реальной ситуацией в памяти. Для некоторого устройства, допустим флешки, я смотрю endpoint context, но в нем не изменяется dequeue pointer, хотя по документации он должен изменяться после обработки каждого TRB (TD). Но если зайти в TRB Ring, то там нет изменения Cycle bit, что ставит меня в тупик еще больше. Как работает этот контроллер? Как там выяснить стоп условие? Какопределить последний исполненный TRB?

Comment: Я провожу исследования и пока поведу диалог сам с собой. Мне удалось выяснить с помощью ядерного отладчика, что в контроллере появляется пустая строка со сменой Cycle bit, видимо она и является стоп условием. Хотя почему это так работает для меня все равно загадка.